# Where is crucial data of wordpress stored?

Tags: wordpress

Some of datas like the menu and its order and themes to be used are important but where does wordpress actually stores it. because I could not find it anywhere neither in database nor some of files. does anyone have any idea about that?

Comment: The selected theme is inside the `wp_options` table, in a row called `template` as I recall.

Comment: And your menues are inside the same table in a row called `theme_mods_{your-theme-name}.` and your menu items is inside `wp_postmeta`

Comment: In most of the cases it stores in `wp_posts` table. Just `post_type` field is different. For Nave menus `post_type` is `nav_menu_item` with a `menu_order` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simply on your database. But the words are slightly modified.